# ¿Cuál es la diferencia entre usar application/xml y text/xml?

Tags: xml, rest, mime

En algunos tutoriales online sobre cómo hacer servicios web REST, si la respuesta va a ser XML se indica que se debe indicar que el tipo devuelto es `application/xml`. Sin embargo, cuando se va a hacer otros elementos en XML, como por ejemplo un sitemap, en algunos sitios se indica que el tipo debería ser `text/xml` y en otros se menciona `application/xml`.

¿Existe alguna diferencia entre usar `application/xml` y `text/xml`? ¿O algún caso en el que usar uno sobre el otro sea mejor?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Vamos a *explorar* alguna respuesta en la definición [RFC 3023](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc3023.txt), la cual fue publicada en 2001 para estandarizar **cinco nuevos tipos de medios** (media type), entre los cuales se encuentran los dos que mencionas en tu pregunta.

El documento dice algo interesante en la introducción:

> Este documento estandariza cinco nuevos tipos de medios: **`text/xml, application/xml, text/xml-external-parsed-entity, aplicación/xml-external-parsed-entity y application/xml-dtd`** para su
> uso en el intercambio de entidades de red que estén relacionadas con
> XML (Xtensible Markup Language).
>
> Este documento también normaliza una convención del sufijo '+ xml')
> para nombrar tipos de medios fuera de estos cinco tipos.
>
> Cuando esos tipos de medios representan entidades XML MIME
> (Multipurpose Internet Mail Extensions). Las entidades XML MIME que se
> intercambian actualmente mediante el protocolo de transferencia de
> hipertexto en la World Wide Web, son parte integrante del protocolo
> WebDAV para la creación remota que se espera que tengan utilidad en
> muchos dominios.

**- ¿Existe alguna diferencia entre usar application/xml y text/xml?**

> `text/xml` and `application/xml` behave differently when the charset  parameter is not explicitly specified.  If the default charset (i.e., US-ASCII) for `text/xml` is inconvenient for some reason (e.g., bad web servers), `application/xml` provides an alternative (see "Optional  parameters" of `application/xml` registration in [Section 3.2](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3023#section-3.2)).  The  same rules apply to the distinction between `text/xml-external-parsed-entity` and `application/xml-external-parsed-entity`.

Traducción [mía]

> `text/xml` y `application/xml` se comportan de manera diferente cuando el conjunto de caracteres no se especifica explícitamente. Si el conjunto de caracteres predeterminado (es decir,  US-ASCII) para `text/xml` es inconveniente por alguna razón (por ejemplo, una web que no lo soporta), `application/xml` proporciona una alternativa (consulte "Optional Parameters" en application/xml registration en [Section 3.2](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3023#section-3.2)).

> Las mismas reglas se aplican a la distinción entre text/xml-external-Parsed-entity y application/xml-external-parsed-entity.

---

**- ¿O algún caso en el que usar uno sobre el otro sea mejor?**

> If an XML document -- that is, the unprocessed, source XML document  -- is readable by casual users, **`text/xml` is preferable to    `application/xml`**.  MIME user agents (and web user agents) that do not have explicit support for `text/xml` will treat it as `text/plain`, for  example, by displaying the XML MIME entity as plain text.

> **`application/xml` is preferable when the XML MIME entity is unreadable by casual users**...

Traducción [mía]:

> Si un documento XML, es decir, el documento XML de origen no procesado es **legible** por usuarios ocasionales, **`text/xml` es preferible a `application/xml`**. Los agentes de usuario MIME (y los agentes de usuario web) que no tienen un soporte explícito para `text/xml` lo tratará como `plain/text`, para mostrar por ejemplo la entidad XML MIME como texto sin formato.
>
> Por el contrario, **`application/xml` es preferible cuando la entidad XML MIME es ilegible para usuarios ocasionales...**

PD:

El documento es extenso, quizá luego encuentre más cosas.

Answer (score 1):

Como ya lo mencionas XML tiene dos Type MIME `application/xml` y `text/xml` y bueno estos dos  en muchas  de las  ocasiones se utilizan de manera indistinta pero hay ana diferencia sutil  y es la razón por la que **application/xml** sea generalmente mas  recomendada a usar.

Acorde al Standard, `text/*- MIME Types` tienen un conjunto de caracteres `US-ASCII` a menos que se especifique lo contrario en los Header HTTP. Esto significa efectivamente que cualquier codificación definida en el prólog XML (por ejemplo, `<? Xml version =”1.0” encoding =” UTF-8” ?>`) Se ignora. Esto por supuesto no es el comportamiento esperado y deseado.

Para complicar más las cosas, la mayoría de las implementaciones del navegador, todas implementan realmente el comportamiento no estándar para `text/xml` porque procesan la codificación como si fuera **application/xml**.

**application/xml** es generalmente el mime type preferido. Para el text/xml aparece la codificación generalmente será tratado como ASCII, independientemente de lo que se especifica en la cabecera del documento XML (a menos que se especifique lo contrario en las cabeceras HTTP).

**Desde el RFC (3023), en la sección 3, XML Media Types:**

> Si un documento XML - es decir, el documento XML sin procesar, fuente
>   - puede ser leído por los usuarios ocasionales, text / xml es preferible application / xml. agentes de usuario (MIME y agentes de
>   usuario web) que no cuentan con el apoyo explícito para el texto / xml
>   lo tratará como text / plain, por ejemplo, mediante la visualización
>   de la entidad MIME XML como texto sin formato. Application / xml es
>   preferible cuando la entidad MIME XML es ilegible para los usuarios
>   ocasionales.

Así, si vas a codificar `text/*`  y no está implementada por los navegadores de una manera compatible con los estándares, dbeebrás usar **application/***.